# select options as progress bar and price range

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm interesting how I can transform select options to progress bar year range. Example of what I want to realize is [avito_filters](https://www.avito.ru/omsk/avtomobili_s_probegom) . In the top filters click "Год выпуска" and you will see example. But I'm interesting, how to realize it.

```
<select class="filter" 
    <option value="771" selected="selected">от 1995 г.в.</option>
    <option value="782">1970</option>
    <option value="873">1980</option>
    <option value="878">1985</option>
    <option value="883">1990</option>
    <option value="884">1991</option>
    <option value="885">1992</option>
    <option value="886">1993</option>
    <option value="887">1994</option>
    <option value="888">1995</option>
    <option value="889">1996</option>
    <option value="890">1997</option>
    <option value="891">1998</option>
    <option value="892">1999</option>
    <option value="893">2000</option>
    <option value="894">2001</option>
    <option value="895">2002</option>
    <option value="896">2003</option>
    <option value="897">2004</option>
    <option value="898">2005</option>
    <option value="899">2006</option>
    <option value="900">2007</option>
    <option value="901">2008</option>
    <option value="902">2009</option>
    <option value="2844">2010</option>
    <option value="2845">2011</option>
    <option value="6045">2012</option>
    <option value="8581">2013</option>
    <option value="11017">2014</option>
    <option value="13978">2015</option>
    <option value="">Год выпуска</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE 2

[jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/) looks pretty cool! It seems way more powerful and customizable!

## UPDATE 1

I've updated my fiddle to support values from a `<select>` element. It's not perfect, just a proof-of-concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/ty8yaksm/13/

[image: new slider]

In the demo, the slider will show the years from the dropdown, and it will respect the changes in the years (i.e. 1980 follows 1970, instead of 1971 following 1970, like in the dropdown).

All I'm doing is keeping track of the index in the range slider, and mapping it to the corresponding `<option>` in the `<select>`. This is kinda hacky, and I'd recommend looking into a more elegant solution, but it's a good start.

**JS**

```
$(function () {

    var select = $('#years')[0];
    var options = select.options;

    var minYear = parseInt(options[0].text);
    var maxYear = parseInt(options[options.length - 1].text);

    var prevMin = minYear,
        prevMax = maxYear,
        prevLeftIndex = 0,
        prevRightIndex = options.length - 1;

    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: options.length - 1,
        values: [0, options.length - 1],
        slide: function (event, ui) {

            var left = ui.values[0],
                right = ui.values[1],
                newMin = minYear,
                newMax = maxYear;

            if (left === prevLeftIndex) {
                newMax = options[right].text;
                prevRightIndex = right;
            }
            else if (right === prevRightIndex) {
                newMin = options[left].text;
                prevLeftIndex = left;
            }

            $('#year-range').val("from: " + newMin + ", to: " + newMax);
            $('#slider-range span').eq(0).text(newMin);
            $('#slider-range span').eq(1).text(newMax);
        }
    });

    // initialize default values
    $('#year-range').val("from: " + minYear + ", to: " + maxYear);
    $('#slider-range span').eq(0).text(minYear);
    $('#slider-range span').eq(1).text(maxYear);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="year-range"></label>
<input id="year-range" type="text" readonly/>
<br/>
<select id="years" readonly>
    <option value="782">1970</option>
    <option value="873">1980</option>
    <option value="878">1985</option>
    <option value="883">1990</option>
    <option value="884">1991</option>
    <option value="885">1992</option>
    <option value="886">1993</option>
    <option value="887">1994</option>
    <option value="888">1995</option>
    <option value="889">1996</option>
    <option value="890">1997</option>
    <option value="891">1998</option>
    <option value="892">1999</option>
    <option value="893">2000</option>
    <option value="894">2001</option>
    <option value="895">2002</option>
    <option value="896">2003</option>
    <option value="897">2004</option>
    <option value="898">2005</option>
    <option value="899">2006</option>
    <option value="900">2007</option>
    <option value="901">2008</option>
    <option value="902">2009</option>
    <option value="2844">2010</option>
    <option value="2845">2011</option>
    <option value="6045">2012</option>
    <option value="8581">2013</option>
    <option value="11017">2014</option>
    <option value="13978">2015</option>
</select>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
input {
    border: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#slider-range {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 4px;
}
```

---

You haven't mentioned anything specific, so until you tell us what your requirements are, you can take a look at jQuery UI's slider:

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

For the `<option>` demo, take a look at this slider (bound to a `<select>` element):

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms

I put together a quick-and-dirty demo to give you an example of how you can use this slider:

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/ty8yaksm/4/

[image: slider preview]

**JS**

```
$(function () {

    // initialize the slider
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: [16, 64],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
            $('#slider-range span').eq(0).text(ui.values[0]);
            $('#slider-range span').eq(1).text(ui.values[1]);
        }
    });

    // initialize default values
    var leftAmount =  $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
    var rightAmount =  $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
    $("#amount").val("$" + leftAmount + " - $" + rightAmount);
    $('#slider-range span').eq(0).text(leftAmount);
    $('#slider-range span').eq(1).text(rightAmount);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <label for="amount">Range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly>
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px 4px;
}
```

Comment: I think you answer with example for options can help. But there is only from low to top value, when I need range slider. I will try to change it.

Comment: I don't know I can't make it's working. Can you show please how your jsfiddle range slider example can work with selector options?

Comment: I will be very grateful!!

Comment: hint: I'm still using the range selector, but I'm using the `select` as input for the values, and manually tracking the indices

Comment: hey @sanchahous, I've updated my code. check it out, and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [jQuery UI Range Selector](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
});

$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

In the code above you see the `.slider` function for turning a div into a range selector but you should specify the arguments.

If you want to select a range, you should define `range : true`, else it is a simple selector.

With `min` and `max` identifiers, you can define minimum value and maximum value.

In the `values` part, you should define an array with two elements to specify the default selected values.

The last part is the `slide` method that gets a function and fires this function when the user slides the thumbs. The first argument is for event args and the second argument is a reference to it self. You can extract the first thumb value with `ui.values[0]` and the second thumb with `ui.values[1]`.

These values can be accessed from any where else with the `.slider` method and two arguments first is what you need `"values"` and the second is the value index.

Comment: Yes I know about this, but how is this connects with options values. How can it work together?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery's .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to build an array and then pass the array to [jQuery's .slider()](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-range).

```
//build the array
var years= []

//add each year to the array
$("option" ).each(function(index,value) {
     years.push(value);
});

//create the slider and pass the array in
$( ".selector" ).slider({
  values: years;
});
```